# Disable sleuth for from storing some traces

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring cloud finchley.rc2 with spring boot version 2 along with sleuth and zipkin.

I have a facade layer which uses reactor project. Facade calls services parallel and each service store some tracing info in rabbit mq.

Issue is I am seeing in zipkin some spans like

```
facade.async
service.publish > Because of mq
```

How can i stop such traces from being captured

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `SpanAdjuster` bean, that will analyze the span information (e.g. span tags) and basing on that information you will change the sampling decision so as not to send it to Zipkin.

Another option is to wrap the default span reporter in a similar logic.

Yet another option is to verify what kind of a thread it is that is creating this span and toggle it off (assuming that it's a `@Scheduled` method) - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RC2/single/spring-cloud.html#__literal_scheduled_literal_annotated_methods